# How to connect two vertices with curved edge

Tags: vertices

Is there a way to do something like this
[image]

from this?
[image]

I've created the first one by adding circle and removing unwanted parts, but what if I couldn't start from scratch and wanted to create it out of two vertices only? Thanks

Comment: Look for the screw tool, Alt R. Set the Pivot to Cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Leander has commented, if you want a circular arc, you can use the Spin tool, (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>) to spin a single radius around the 3D cursor.

If you want a more arbitrary curve interpolating through control points, you can select and position those points on an existing boundary, and use the shipped add-on: Loop Tools > 'Curve' to form it.

[image]